# NoSuchMethodError using fasterxml jackson

Tags: spring-4, fasterxml, jackson2

I am getting this error when running a spring application and using a `RestTemplate`
However when running a junit test I see no problem
In my test I generate this json.

```
[ 
  {
    "idProcesoElectoral": 9,
    "idSolicitud": 591,
    "folioSiilnere": "E1009000591",
    "idEstatusSolicitud": 2,
    "fechaEstatus": "25/10/17 13:13:51"
  }
]
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:830)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:617)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
```

I have read that it is probably a version conflict somewhere, but can't find the culprit.

Here are the jackson libraries included

```
./siilnere-web/target/siilnere-web-6.4.1.0.5/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.2.3-beta5.jar
./siilnere-web/target/siilnere-web-6.4.1.0.5/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.8.9.jar
./siilnere-web/target/siilnere-web-6.4.1.0.5/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar
./siilnere-web/target/siilnere-web-6.4.1.0.5/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.9.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.2.3-beta5.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.8.9.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar
./siilnere-ear/target/siilnere-ear-6.4.1.0.5/APP-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.9.jar
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thankyou

Edit:
I read a suggestion to temporarily use java parameter -verbose:class to try to debug this.

I greped the output of weblogic and got this
and found statements like this (though I didn't find any like refering to class ObjectWriter):

```
Loaded com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer from file:/opt/Oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind.jar
```

However I have this in weblogic.xml:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom?

Comment: Don't know if posting pom.xml will help. I only declare the jackson libraries above. The project is an ear with 4 subprojects, one of which is a war and another a jar. Both include the dependencies for the purpouse of debugging this problem only.